# iOS system volume change to achive 9dB boost

Tags: ios

How to chnage iOS system volume such that it matches with 9dB digital boost?

(Output after Analog system volume change) = (9dB digital boosted signal before system volume change)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manipulate the audio stream directly if you want to do something like that: system volume on iOS doesn't match to any sort of decibel scale - how could it? An iPad has a very different set of speakers to, say, an iPod Touch.